# Компонент высшего порядка React делает рендер во всех его дочерних компонентах

Tags: reactjs

Всем привет.

Есть компонент высшего порядка в котором описана одна логика для нескольких компонентов.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const searchPatient = (View) => {
    return class extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.handleOutsideClick = this.handleOutsideClick.bind(this);
            this.escFunction = this.escFunction.bind(this);
        }

        state = {isList: false};

        componentDidMount() {
            document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleOutsideClick);
            document.addEventListener("keydown", this.escFunction);
        };

        componentWillUnmount() {
            document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleOutsideClick);
            document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.escFunction);
        };

        handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
            const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
            if (node && !node.contains(e.target)) this.setState({isList: false});
        };

        escFunction = (event) => {
            if (event.keyCode === 27) this.setState({isList: false});
        };

        changeIsList = (isList) => this.setState({isList});

        render() {
            return <View {...this.props} isList={this.state.isList} changeIsList={this.changeIsList} />
        }
    }
};

export default searchPatient;
```

Это компонент полей поиска по списку.

Поиск может быть по фамилии, имени или номеру телефона не важно.

```
export default searchPatient(PhoneField)
export default searchPatient(LastNameField)
```

И допустим когда я ввожу номер телефона то список подгружается и фамилию(списки прилетают через пропсы и значение value в инпуты тоже)

```
<PhoneField                     
       value={this.state.personalPhone}
       onChange={this.handlePhoneField}
       patientList={this.state.patientList}
/>
```

Этот компонент изолирован он предыдущего и находится в другом компоненте и вызывается по другому:

```
<LastNameField
     value={this.state.lastName}
     onChange={this.handleLastNameField}
     patientList={this.state.patientList}
/>
```

И допустим компоненту LastNameField Не нужно знать о patientList компонента PhoneField. Потому что поле LastNameField находиться абсолютно в другом компоненте. Как сделать так что бы эти два компонента не контактировали друг с другом?

Comment: Серьезно `findDOMNode()` в 2019-ом ?

Comment: XD Ну это я скопировал с простор гугла XD Для того что бы в не компонента клик поймать )) Если есть совет как сделать лучше буду рад)))

Comment: Пробрасывайте через `props` в компонент `LastNameField` и `PhoneField` список `patientList` из родительского для них компонента, тогда они будут изолированы друг от друга и просто будут ждать эту общую для двоих пропсу.